# Rails - Dynamically Login People

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app and when user clicks to login button on header a bootstrap popup modal opens with a form, asks for user email and password. When user types and presses enter, I use  `window.location.reload();` and the button login turns in to a button with a text says `"Welcome <%= current_user.name %>"`

What I want to do is, instead of using window location reload, can I update this dynamically?

Here is my `sessions#create` action

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    respond_to do |format|
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     if user.activated? 
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)

        format.html { redirect_back_or user }
        flash[:notice] = t('flash.sessions.create.success.html')
        format.js #here I should do smth
     else
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render json: {email:['Account not activated. Check your email for the activation link.']} , status: :unprocessable_entity}
        format.js   { render json: {email:['Account not activated. Check your email for the activation link.']}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

then the `create.js.erb`

```
// close modal

    $('#login-dialog').fadeToggle();
    // clear form input elements
    // todo/note: handle textarea, select, etc
    $('form input[type="text"]').val('');

     //Clear previous errors
    $('.form-group.has-error').each(function(){
    $('.help-block').html('');
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    });

    window.location.reload(); #here I am reloading the page then I can see login button disappears and new button saying Welcome Billy appears.
```

So how can I do that without reloading the window.
Thank you

**EDIT**

The thing is, I have also signup modal which user can click to open and these modal codes are in header.html.erb, when I render the page as you suggested it gives an error for sign up form;

```
<% modal ||= false %>
<% remote = modal ? true : false %>
<%= form_for(@user, remote: modal, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'user'})  do |f| %>


<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, t('header.nameSurname') %>    
    <span class="help"></span>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :username, t('header.username') %> 
    <span class="help"></span>   
    <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
....
```

because of `@user` variable, if I change it to `User.new` is it ok?, would it create problem?.

I also have 3 different header partials. I normally render them in application.html.erb as;

```
<div id="render_main">  
   <% if @header_main %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header_main' %>  <!--Header comes here--> 
    <% elsif @header_listing %>

    <%= render 'layouts/header_listing' %>  <!--Header comes here--> 
    <% else  %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

But then in create.js.erb;

```
// close modal

    $('#login-dialog').fadeToggle();
    // clear form input elements
    // todo/note: handle textarea, select, etc
    $('form input[type="text"]').val('');

     //Clear previous errors
    $('.form-group.has-error').each(function(){
    $('.help-block').html('');
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    });

    //window.location.reload();


    <% if @header_main %>
    $('#render_main').html('<%= j render "layouts/header_main"%>')
    <% elsif @header_listing %>

    $('#render_main').html('<%= j render "layouts/header_listing"%>')
    <% else  %>
    $('#render_main').html('<%= j render "layouts/header"%>')
    <% end %>
```

as I render it can not find @header_main variable I believe, so It does not work as it should be. How can I fix this?.

Main controller;

```
before_action :show_main_header, only: [:home]
 def show_main_header
    @header_main = true
  end
```

Considering user login, from main controller home action. But it is probably because I actually run from session#create action. how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

firstly, thank you Rodrigo,

I have written a function to hold last action;

```
def location_action_name
    if !logged_in?
      url = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)
      @last_action = url[:action]
    end
  end
```

Then I write to create.js.erb;

```
 <% if (@last_action == "home") %>
    $('#render_main').html('<%= j render "layouts/header_main"%>')
    <% elsif (@last_action == "listings") %>

    $('#render_main').html('<%= j render "layouts/header_listing"%>')
    <% else  %>
    $('#render_main').html('<%= j render "layouts/header"%>')
    <% end %>
```

and worked! in case anyone wonders..

Comment: I didn't understand why you're rendering the sign up form in header. Anyway, if you rerender the header after the user login, this form shouldn't be rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have an partial view for render the header (`app/views/shared/_header.html.erb`), what you need to do is rerender this partial and replace the header html:

**create.js.erb**

```
// window.location.reload();
$('#header-container').html('<%= j render "shared/header"%>')
```

**EDIT:**

If the `@header_main` and `@header_listing` variables are used to render the header partial, you'll need to instantiate them in your `sessions#create` action.

To do this, add the `show_main_header` filter to `SessionsController` too.